# How to use AngularJS 1 in Ag-Grid filters?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ag-grid

I want to create a filter for Ag-Grid 5.2.0 in AngularJS. Here is my code:

```
    var columnDefs = [
        {headerName: "Test1", field: "test1", filter: MyCustomFilter},
        {headerName: "Test2", field: "test2"},
    ];         

    vm.gridOptions = {
        enableServerSideSorting: true,
        enableServerSideFilter: true,
        columnDefs: columnDefs,
        datasource: getDataSource(),
        paginationPageSize: 10,
        rowModelType: 'pagination'
    };

    // Class function.
    function MyCustomFilter() {}

    // mandatory methods
    MyCustomFilter.prototype.init = function (params) {};
    MyCustomFilter.prototype.getGui = function () {return "<div>{{ 'testkey' | translate}}</div>"};
    MyCustomFilter.prototype.isFilterActive = function() {return true;};
    MyCustomFilter.prototype.doesFilterPass = function (params) { return true;};
    MyCustomFilter.prototype.getApi = function () {};
```

The problem is that AngularJS does not evaluate the translate filter. How can I add AngularJS elements to an Ag-Grid filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the solution:

```
function getGui() {
    var filterScope = $rootScope.$new(true);
    var filter = $compile("<div>{{ 'testkey' | translate}}</div>")(filterScope);
    filterScope.$digest();
    return filter[0];
};
```